# Wallet files in a Dapp

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am developing an application from the `truffle webpack` and I have created my own wallet, adding my account to a json file:

```
 $.getJSON('../wallet.json', function(data) {
        var password = "xxx";
        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedWallet(json, password).then(function(wallet) {...})
```

Everything works, but I have a problem with Browser-sync. It recognizes that something is being changed all time and my web is reloading constantly since I am mining and the wallet balance changes. I would like to know which file is changing to ignore it.